# How to update and delete files in MongoDB database with Next.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, next.js

When I'm trying to update/delete file from MongoDB I'm always getting mistakes, one or another. I understand the logic behind the interaction for this task, but I cannot do the right details for the function to work. Set up is like this:

The function for communication with database is imported into the file like:

```
import { dat } from '../../../const/dat';
```

I know it works properly since I'm getting data from database.

Database setup is standard. It has the database itself in this database it has several collections in which data is stored. I am trying to delete data from offers, recognized by its `_id`.

The function from which I'm trying to delete files has already two actions in it. First create file and else show array of files. I'm trying to attach to each file the button when `onClick` action happens file with the current id will be deleted.

So here is the function itself:

```
const getList = (arr, id) => {
    if(!arr) return null;
    const res = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i ++) {
        let flag = false;
        if(typeof arr[i] === 'object') res.push(
            <div key={Object.keys(arr[i])[0]}>
                <div>{Object.keys(arr[i])[0]}</div>
            </div>)
        else res.push(
            <div key={arr[i]}>
                <a href={'/'+id+'/'+arr[i]} download>{arr[i]}</a>
                //<button onClick={()=>arr.splice(i,1)}>delete</button>
                //{request.bind(null, {query: 'delete', _id: _id})}
                <div onClick={request.bind(null, {query: 'delete', _id: id})}>delete</div>
            </div>)
    }
    return res;
}
```

The function by itself works. I just cannot get delete portion of it working.

This line:

```
<button onClick={()=>arr.splice(i,1)}>delete</button>
```

works, but it deletes the array which is in the function itself so when reload page a deleted member of an array returns back.

This line seems the right way to go:

```
<div onClick={request.bind(null, {query: 'delete', _id: id})}>delete</div>
```

But it gives me the series of faults, the first of which is request is not defined. When I'm trying to just use the query part it gives the other faults.

I tried to adopt the code from here: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_delete.asp
But it gives hard time too.

Comment: Where is `getList` being called from? Are you trying to do database operations from client-side code?

Comment: Hello! getList function gets called from: pages/personal/components tree... the page itself is connected by nextjs automatic routing system... it sits in the account of user, shows the list of documents of the client and the idea is to attach the delete button to each document. So while we looping through the array, we attach the del button to each item of the array... And generally I can see the button, but somehow I cannot make it work properly...

Comment: the button is bind by id, which correlates to _id in the mongodb database of offers collection... So I just need to do the right request from this page/from this function to mongodb... Somehow I cannot do this, I have the series of faults...

Comment: I guess the narrow question would be: how to do the right query to offers collection in a database, from this function. I tried arrow function, with database request, but it seems too simple way and database doesn't listen to the request... I tried await function that seems the right way to go? with the query choice and connection for the choice I will try to update my question...

Comment: You can't have database operations in client-side code. You'll need to move those operations to an API route on the server, then call the API in your component.

Comment: oh... I see... Could you advise any source where I can look it up? I might be looking in the wrong places... Since I was leaning towards wrong solution...

Comment: I looked up through many crud examples, but they somehow don't pay too much attention to the delete operations... I guess it's because very simple? But somehow I never saw any mentions of API as a middle guy between next and mongo... Vice versa I saw many example where they go straight to mongo from the page...